# What should I do about a recessed light without a housing?

Tags: electrical

I looked into my attic today and found one recessed light mounted directly in the ceiling (sheetrock) without a can/fixture. Isn't it dangerous (in terms of fire hazard) to have so.

What do you guy suggest, should I put a remodeling can in it?

Comment: Many remodel cans are just like this. We'd need a name and model, or a photo, to tell if it's correct or not.

Comment: by roof do you mean ceiling?

Comment: @Brad, correct its ceiling.

Comment: @Speedy, Here is the link to the light bulb http://www.amazon.com/RL560WH6835R-Recessed-3500K-Retrofit-Baffle/dp/B00F2WRO50

Comment: On the plus side, the fire risk from an LED bulb like that one is lower than from an incandescent or halogen.

Comment: A 9.4 watt LED runs so cool, the usual prime reason for a can (heat-based fire protection) is moot.  Keeping insulation and debris out of the works is still a consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the trim kit shown in the comments is all that is there then absolutely yes, it needs a line voltage housing installed first. The kit linked is made to retrofit a Halo H7 housing.